# How to ensure that random UIColors are visible on a white background in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I'm using this code to generate a random `UIColor` for `UILabel` text in an `ios app` with a white background.

- Problem is that some of the text turns out to be invisible against the white background.
- How would you modify the code to ensure that any color chosen would be reasonably visible on a white background.

This question is as much about colors as it is programming.

```
+ (UIColor *) randomColor {
    CGFloat red =  (CGFloat)arc4random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat blue = (CGFloat)arc4random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
    CGFloat green = (CGFloat)arc4random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
}
```

Comment: If you goal to only accept colors that work on a white background or do you want a way to pick a different background color based on the random color?

Comment: You could limit how close the RGB values can get to 1.

Comment: @rmaddy that's an interesting idea but it might be difficult in my situation because I'll be generating up to 11 items  each with a random color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would do is determine the "gray" level of the RGB value. If it's "too close to white", then try again.

A formula I've used is:

```
float gray = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue;
```

This gives 0 for black and 1 for white. Pick a threshold such as 0.6 or whatever works for you.

```
+ (UIColor *) randomColor {
    while (1) {
        CGFloat red =  (CGFloat)arc4random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
        CGFloat blue = (CGFloat)arc4random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
        CGFloat green = (CGFloat)arc4random()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX;
        CGFloat gray = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue;
        if (gray < 0.6) {
            return [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the best answer. Do you really need a gray value less than .6 in order to make the color show up against white? That's a pretty dark minimum gray value.

Comment: Thanks, that problem is solved. As you've used this before, i wonder if you noticed that the colors don't appear to be particularly random, or rather evenly distributed. There's definitely some clumping.  This was happening even before your gray formula was added. Here's an example screenshot http://imgur.com/At5yTyY

Comment: @DuncanC The `0.6` value is just a guess. The OP needs to pick what works.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil I've never used this code before. I simply had the code to calculate a gray-level from an RGB value.

Comment: @DuncanC I'm playing with that number now. In fact making it a higher value helps the other problem I noted above.

Answer (score 1):

white  is 1, 1,1. I think you can hack it so that as you generate colors you do multiple tries till you values are not to close to 1.0 1.0 1.0.  really if one was .5 the rest were close to 1.0 your fine. statistically you should reach a color that meets the rules in a few tries.  You would through inspection have to see what threshold is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I think Maddy's answer is the best answer you've gotten.

Another, similar approach would be to calculate the Pythagorean distance between your color and the background color. Pseudocode, where the two colors are red1/green1/blue1 and red2/blue2/green2

```
CGFloat difference = sqrt( (red1 - red2)^2 + (green1 - green2)^2 + 
(blue1 - blue2)^2 );
```

That approach would let you find colors that are different from any arbitrary background color. To allow for human color perception, you could also use the weight values from Maddy's grayscale formula:

```
CGFloat difference = sqrt( 0.299 * (red1 - red2)^2 + 0.587 * (green1 - green2)^2 + 
0.114 * (blue1 - blue2)^2 );
```

Better still would be to convert the RGB values to LAB color space and compare the distance between colors in LAB space, but that's way beyond the scope of this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd be interested to see the non-pseudo version, as the method I have to create random colors doesn't seem to create them with even distribution.

Comment: As I say, the best way would be to generate your random colors in LAB space, check the Pythagorean distance between colors in LAB space, then convert back to RGB for display. LAB is a better color model for evenly spacing colors based on human color perception. That's what it's designed for.

Comment: Another approach to random colors would be to generate random values using the ranges Maddy provides, then multiply each random value to normalize it to a value in the range 0-1. (The human eye is much more sensitive to green than to red or blue. You want very large changes in blue value between colors, smaller changes in red value, and the smallest change in green values between colors.)

Answer (score 0):

The (R,G,B) turns to white when the values are closer to 255, 255, 255. So, make your random number generator to not to generate too close numbers to 255 for any of these colors.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Not really. (255,0,0) (red) would look fine on white.

Comment: Yes. (R,G,B) is a combination tuple. So, my answer will work.